# Ionic 4, Android Studio, Gradle, Java jdk or Cordova error

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I am trying to test if the qr-scanner for my Ionic 4 app is working so I need to test my application on an android device (tablet).
I used the command: *ionic cordova run android* in my Visual Studio Code command prompt but I keep getting errors. My latest error is:

> cordova.cmd run android
>   Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
>   ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
>   Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
>   or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
>   in your path, or install Android Studio
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>   cordova.cmd run android exited with exit code 1.
>   Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

I have downloaded/installed and configured Android Studio, Java jdk, Gradle and Cordova as all the solutions I have tried suggests but I keep getting more errors as I progress. Even after setting the user environmental variable ANDROID_HOME and system environmental variable PATH and restarting my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you are not running your Visual Studio Code as Admin.
So it cannot access the displayed paths.

Regards,
Markus

Comment: This worked for me thanks. I have installed java and android studio in root directories.